# Existence of $E[X]$ and $\text{Var}[X]$.

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions, expected-value

> For the CDF
> $$F(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> 1-\dfrac{1-e^{-x}}{x}, & x > 0 \\[1mm]
> 0, & x \le 0
> \end{cases}$$
> find the characteristics $E[X]$, $\text{Var}[X]$.

I differentiated to find PDF and got
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1-(1+x)e^{-x}}{x^2}, & x > 0 \\[1mm]
0, & x \le 0
\end{cases}$$

So we have
$$E[X] = \int_0^\infty x\cdot \dfrac{1-(1+x)e^{-x}}{x^2} dx = \int_{0}^\infty \frac{1-(1+x)e^{-x}}{x}dx$$
which seems to diverge comparing to $\dfrac1x$ when $x\to0$. So, I think the expectation and therefore variance do not exist. Am I right?

Comment: I would say the mean is infinite and the variance does not exist.

Comment: @Momo Ok I got it.

Comment: Your answer is correct but your reasoning is wrong. The expected value integral does not diverge near $0$, but near $\infty$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Oh yes, near $0$ the numerator goes to $0$, so at $\infty$ the integral diverges. Thanks.

Comment: A useful fact for when the random variable is non-negative: $E[X] = \int (1 - F(x))\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: @Joe This is nice! Thank you.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if $\mathbb E[|X|^p]$ exists for some $p>0$ then $\mathbb E[|X|^q]$ exists for $0\leqslant q<p$.